# How to pass java object to mysql stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql

I need to validate all values from the master tables by the service call in java. But it takes more time for execution. So I planned to do the task on the MySQL stored procedure.

For Example:

I have a POJO class called **User**

```
User user = new User();
user.setId(1);
user.setName("name");
```

Can I pass the **user** java object to MySQL stored procedure?

Comment: Google for your favorite tutorial for calling MySQL stored procedures from Java.  Here's one:  https://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/jdbc-examples-for-calling-stored-procedures-mysql

Comment: short answer is no, MySQL can't be passed a Java object per se.  MySQL works in primitives like integers and strings (`char`/`varchar`), and doesn't understand objects in any language.  If the data is coming from SQL and going into a stored procedure, using pure SQL for this would make sense to me; you can use java to analyze the results once they're ready.

Comment: Separate your concerns. Your relational database should not be dependent on your objects.

Answer (score 2):

No, we can't pass a java object as a parameter to a MySQL stored procedure.

A MySQL stored procedure can have zero, one or more *scalar* parameters. Arguments are simple datatypes such as DATETIME, DECIMAL, INT, VARCHAR, et al.